# How to save an image to desktop using TestComplete?

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I'm writing tests in JScript in TestComplete. I need to make a screenshot of a web page element, and save it to my desktop as a PNG file.

I tried this code:

```
var MyPicture = WebPage.SomeLocation.Picture();

MyPicture.SaveToFile("C:\Desktop");
```

which doesn't seem to be working, and I can't seem to figure out why. My program doesn't crash or anything, it simply doesn't save the picture. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is on my list of "Top 10 vaguest SO questions" and almost my favorite :)

Comment: I'm not intentially trying to make it vague. All I'm trying to ask is how to save a picture object to my desktop through scripting in testcomplete. What can I do to make it more clear?

Comment: @Phil: It's a perfectly clear question to TestComplete users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SaveToFile`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/74446/) needs a full name of the image to create, including a path. Remember that in JScript you must double the backslashes in paths.

To get the desktop folder path, you can use the [`SpecialFolders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe(v=vs.84).aspx) property.

```
var MyPicture = WebPage.SomeLocation.Picture();
var strImageName = "MyPicture.png";

// Get the Desktop folder path
var strDesktop = Sys.OleObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop");
// Build the full path to the image
var strPath = aqFileSystem.IncludeTrailingBackSlash(strDesktop) + strImageName;

MyPicture.SaveToFile(strPath);
```